# How to create an ad using Facebook Marketing API for PHP?

Tags: facebook-php-sdk

I followed https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/buying-api#ad-creative but it didn't work. I stuck at creating `AdImage`.

```
Api::init($facebook_appid, $facebook_appsecret, $facebook_accesstoken);

$image = new AdImage(null, $facebook_accountid);
$image->{AdImageFields::FILENAME} = '/path/to/file.jpg';
$image->create();
echo 'Image Hash: ', $image->{AdImageFields::HASH}, PHP_EOL;
```

I got:

```
$parent_id as a parameter of constructor is being deprecated, please try not to use this in new code.
```

But assigning account id to a field doesnt work either:

```
Api::init($facebook_appid, $facebook_appsecret, $facebook_accesstoken);

$image = new AdImage();
$image->{AdImageFields::ACCOUNT_ID} = $facebook_accountid;
$image->{AdImageFields::FILENAME} = public_path('demo/banners/coworking-300x250.png');
$image->create();
echo 'Image Hash: ', $image->{AdImageFields::HASH}, PHP_EOL;
```

I got:

```
A parent ID is required.
```

-- UPDATE --

The following should work for images:

```
Api::init($facebook_appid, $facebook_appsecret, $facebook_accesstoken);

$account = new AdAccount($facebook_accountid);
$image = $account->createAdImage([], [
    AdImageFields::FILENAME => public_path('demo/banners/coworking-300x250.png'),
]);
```

The current problem is - how to create account for testing...

Answer (score 0):

i have same problem with you. My problem solved by using setParentId() function from AbstractCrudObject.php file.

Do change your code like this, hope it helps

```
$image = new AdImage();
$image->setParentId("act_somenumber");
```